# How to get users from @many-to-many created bases

Tags: spring, spring-data-jpa

I created two classes User and Events. They are associated with many to many annotations. I need to find some variants of how to get all users from one event, or how to get all events from one user.

I trying to find some guides but didn't found.

User class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "usr")
public class User implements UserDetails {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    @Column(name = "id", updatable = false, nullable = false)
    private Long id;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String username;

    @NotNull
    @Column(nullable = false, length = 60)
    private String password;

    private boolean active;

    @ElementCollection(targetClass = Role.class , fetch = FetchType.EAGER)
    @CollectionTable(name = "user_role" , joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id"))
    @Enumerated(EnumType.STRING)
    private Set<Role> roles;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable (name="user_event",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn (name="user_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="event_id"))
    private List<Events> events;

}
```

Event class

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "events")
public class Events {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.AUTO)
    private long id;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String place;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 40)
    private String title;

    @Column(nullable = false, length = 2048)
    private String text;

    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "dateStart")
    private java.util.Date dateStart;

    @Basic
    @Temporal(TemporalType.DATE)
    @Column(name = "dateEnd")
    private java.util.Date dateEnd;

    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name="student_university",
            joinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="event_id"),
            inverseJoinColumns=@JoinColumn(name="user_id"))
    private List<User> universities;

}
```

And what now... I need something which should give me events by user-id or users by event-id in the controller. I don't know how to make it.

Answer (score 0):

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
  List<User> findAllByEventsId(Long id)
}

public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Event, Long> {
  List<Event> findAllByUniversitiesId(Long id)
}
```

Then use theese repository-methods in your controllers.

Answer (score 0):

You can join table

```
public class User {
    @ManyToMany
    @JoinTable(name = "a_user_event",
            joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "user_id", referencedColumnName = "id"),
            inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "event_id", referencedColumnName = "id"))
    private List<Events> events;
}

public class Events {
    @ManyToMany(mappedBy = "events")
    private List<User> users;
}
```

And on your repository

```
public interface UserRepository extends JpaRepository<User, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT u FROM User u inner join u.events e WHERE e.id = ?1")
    public List<User> findUsersByEventId(long eventId);
}

public interface EventRepository extends JpaRepository<Events, Long> {
    @Query("SELECT e FROM User u inner join u.events e WHERE u.id = ?1")
    public List<Events> findEventsByUserId(long userId);
}
```